# How to display data from node.js api returning a an array of obect to react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get specific values from an array object returned by my node.js api

Here's the array of object returned by my node.js api

```
[
  {
    "name": "device1",
    "serial": "WMD105222022",
    "status": "online"
  },
  {
    "name": "device2q",
    "serial": "sdfsdf",
    "status": "online"
  },
  {
    "name": "ducs",
    "serial": "WMD105222022",
    "status": "online"
  }
]
```

Here's my react.js code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import './Module.css';
import {SDH} from '../../components';
import {temp, water, humidity, nutrient} from '../../assets';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from "axios";

const Module = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
    const [device, setDevice] = useState({});

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3020/getdevice", {
            params: { 
              email: email
            }
          })
          .then((response) => {
            setDevice(response.data);
          })
          // .then((response) => {},
          //   (err) => {
          //     alert("No Data To Show");
          //   }
          // )
          .catch((err) => {
            return false;
          });
    },[]);

    const DisplayData = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <td>{device.name}</td>
          <td>{device.serial}</td>
          <td>{device.status}</td>
        </div>
      );
    };

    return (
        <div className="MainBodyM">
            <SDH/>
            <h3 className="deviceStatus"></h3>
            {/* <Button onClick={getDevices} variant="primary" type="submit">Refresh List</Button> */}
            <div className="tempHeader">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Serial Number</td>
                    <td>Status</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      {DisplayData}
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            
            <Link to="/registerdevice">
                <Button>Add Control Module</Button>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Module;
```

I needed to get the `name, serial, and status` to be displayed in a table. up until now i'm still getting nowhere, please help, i'm only using `{JSON.stringify(device, null, 3)}` to display the returned array of object that's why i know i'm getting an array of object. I'm open to suggestions and correction. Thank you.

I need the output to be like this, regardless how many devices/data i add in array of object.

```
Device      Serial             Status
Device1     121                online
device2     234135             offline
balcony     ash3               online
bathroom    dsgfkahaskj23      online
so on...    tj2l5              offline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send an array from the backend. You must send a JSON

**In express**

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    array: [
      {
        name: "device1",
        serial: "WMD105222022",
        status: "online",
      },
      {
        name: "device2q",
        serial: "sdfsdf",
        status: "online",
      },
      {
        name: "ducs",
        serial: "WMD105222022",
        status: "online",
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

> Note that I send a JSON, not an array

**In React:**

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    var config = {
      method: "get",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/test",
      headers: {},
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        const data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        const array = JSON.parse(data).array;
        setData(array);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

> Note that I convert the JSON to an object to be able to iterate it

**the return on the component**

```
  <table>
    {data &&
      data.map((row, key) => {
        return (
          <tr key={key} style={{ color: "red" }}>
            <td>{row.name}</td>
            <td>{row.serial}</td>
            <td>{row.status}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
  </table>
```

Comment: Remember that they are asynchronous calls; the value is not available and ready to render until the data arrives; that takes time, so you must validate that you have the data before iterating.  {data &&
          data.map((row, key) => {})

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the columns name, ie. `"Device", "Serial", "Status"`, into an array, and iterate over them using `map` function:

```
  const [data, setDate] = useState();
  const columns = ["Device", "Serial", "Status"]; // hard code the columns

  const lookUpDataKey = {
    Device: "name",
    Serial: "serial",
    Status: "status"
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setDate(dataFromApi); // mimic getting data from api
  }, []);

  if (!data) return <div>loading</div>;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        {columns.map((column, columnIndex) => (
          <div key={columnIndex}>
            {/* Column name */}
            <div>{columns[columnIndex]}</div>

            {/* Column data */}
            {data.map((item, dataIndex) => (
              <div key={dataIndex}>
                <div>{item[lookUpDataKey[column]]}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Notice we use a `lookUpDataKey` object for matching column's name to the corresponding object key.

Try it out in updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-hooks-1j98l1).

Comment: i'm getting a ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')``` i thought this would work too but not sure what's going on with it.

Comment: Did you forget to initilize the columns array: `const columns = ["name", "serial", "status"];` ? Where's does the error come from?

Comment: my bad, this works but i have an issue, after adding a new data it doesn't show since it's tide on the number of columns, and the data shows in one column, how can i change that to show only the name of devices under column name and serial numbers only in serial column and so on

Comment: but i have an issue, after adding a new data it doesn't show since it's tide on the number of columns, and the data shows in one column, how can i change that to show only the name of devices under column name and serial numbers only in serial column and so on.... i also update the kind of output i need on my question, regardless how many data i add on my array of objects